# VBA perform an autofilter and then delete data from specific columns

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am performing an autofilter in vba and would subsequently like to delete visible data from the last columns in the sheet (in code LastRWMC and LastCWMC are the last row and column respectively). however the code attached wants to delete the entire row, which I do not want to do. I have tried selecting which selects the correct data but when I go to delete it deletes the entire row.

I want to delete from column twenty onwards.

```
ws5.Range(ws5.Cells(2,20),ws5.Cells(LastRWMC,LastCWMC)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisile).delete
```

Comment: You want to find the last row and delete working upwards (larger row# to smaller row#), check if the row is visible and check if the row is > 20, if so Delete the row.  That is the outline for what you are asking to do.

Comment: it was the .delete, I should have used .clear